# Is it possible to import a Maya file into blender?

Tags: import, file-format

I have Maya files from Maya 2012 (or 2013) and I was wondering if there was a way to import the Maya file into blender?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not directly (since the ma .. mb formats are closed or licensed I think? don't quote me), but you can export your model from Maya to a universal format that Blender supports such as `.abc`, `.fbx`, `.dae` or `.obj` and then import into Blender using the *File > Import* menu. Use either of the first two if you have an armature and .`fbx` preferably if you have animation data.