# How to import a rig and animation from maya?

Tags: animation, rigging, import, external-applications

Whenever I export the file from maya to fbx and import into blender, the rig changes and the animation it doesn't work like it should.

I tried exporting to a dae and importing into blender, but there's nothing. No mesh or anything.

Here's the [maya file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/czccfp6rrcnvx2d/book4.ma?dl=0).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to import a Maya file into blender?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22955/is-it-possible-to-import-a-maya-file-into-blender)

Comment: The problem is that whenever I exported the maya file as a fbx and imported into blender the rig changes.. and when I play the animation it doesn't work like it should when it's in maya and when I exported the maya file into dae and imported into blender there's nothing. no mesh no anything. Sorry if I wasn't very clear on my question.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question to  try and make it more clear and readable. Feel free to rollback and/or make your own edits if you disagree with mine :)

Comment: Could you add an export to .fbx the .ma file cannot be imported to Blender.

Comment: Yes, we need the .fbx file as well. And this shall probably be reported as bug on [our tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug)… with the fbx file. ;)

Comment: Oh thanks for editing it. Yes it became more direct to the point sorry I'm not really that good in english. Oh sure, here's the .fbx [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/phtbk35nljv43p7/lalalala.fbx?dl=0) and also the .dae [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvz5q8i5yoambzs/try.dae?dl=0). And can anyone please explain to me why the rigging isn't working correctly?

Comment: AFAIK, the FBX importer works with maya armatures, but not maya constraints

Comment: So it's impossible? I want to study how he made the rigging for our school project but the maya interface is really confusing. -_-

Comment: .fbx should work but I have found .mdd is always my go to next... try updating your blender version or reseting to defaults, because the .fbx export should work

Answer (score 4):

In past year we used Maya for aditional effects on characters (especially for cloth simulations) and we discovered that the best way to import is `.mdd`.

This format transfers the maya animation and convert it into animated shapes keys:

1. Get your first pose (in maya) and export as `.obj` object
2. Export the animation from maya as `.mdd`
3. Import the `.obj` object in blender
4. Select your object and import the animation as `.mdd`

*Always check "keep vertex orders".*

Answer (score 2):

I have had a look at the maya file. The reason no animation is coming in by FBX, is it is done with expressions, mesh deformers and other maya nodes.

while blender would be able to do a similar effect, blenders internals are very different from maya, and there is no way to import the setup from an FBX file.