# Blender animation import issue

Tags: animation, mesh

Im tying to import an animation from Maya LT to blender in order to make a render
I have severall problems trying to do so.
If i export it in fbx Blender separates my mesh, its a coffe cup rocket and the wings get separated from the model
[image]
I tried with .mdd and the animation works perfectly fine but Blender does this to my mesh
[image]

Help, please!

Comment: As stated here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22955/is-it-possible-to-import-a-maya-file-into-blender try fbx. And if you have problem with it, could you post it somewhere for further 'investigation'?

Comment: it was a problem of Rigging in maya that exported the fbx like that , I realized this fix it and the problem was solved